# JFXtras and Netbeans compiler issue

Tags: netbeans, javafx, jfxtras

Would somebody be able to walk me through the proper way of adding the latest JFXtras package to a project in Netbeans? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... whether it be importing incorrectly, implementing incorrectly, or just simply downloading the wrong jar files. I'm using JavaFX 1.3 and NetBeans 6.9.

I've been able to get NetBeans to recognize the components in the library (I type XCustomNode, and it prompts me to import from org.​jfxtras.​scene.) Upon trying to build/run, however, I get a compiler error such as the following:

```
Note: An internal error has occurred in the OpenJFX compiler. Please file a bug at the Openjfx-compiler issues home (https://openjfx-compiler.dev.java.net/Issues) after checking for duplicates.  Include in your report:
- the following diagnostics
- file C:\Documents and Settings\me\Local Settings\Temp\javafx_err_4220242024568343160.txt
- and if possible, the source file which triggered this problem. Thank you. C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\project\src\input\NumberWithLabelNode.fx:24: cannot access com.sun.javafx.runtime.location.ObjectVariable class file for com.sun.javafx.runtime.location.ObjectVariable not found public class NumberWithLabelNode extends XCustomNode { 1 error
```

I don't think I really need to go report this to Openjfx... my gut says I'm missing a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what version of JFXtras you're using, but I've had much better success with version 0.7rc alongside JavaFX 1.3.

In addition to making sure Common and Controls jars in in your library, I've had to add miglayout-3.7.jar and swing-worker-1.2.jar as well, available on the [project downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/jfxtras/downloads/list)

Comment: Excellent. I'm pretty sure that was my issue... I'll post back here if I run into any more problems. By the way... do you happen to know if jfxtras 0.7 documentation exists? 

Thanks so much!

Comment: Best thing I could ever find was the jfxtras 0.6 javadocs at http://jfxtras.googlecode.com/svn/site/javadoc/release-0.6/index.html

Comment: Yeah, same here. Makes me a little hesitant to adopt it into the project. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is incorrect version of library. You are trying to use JFXtras compiled with JavaFX 1.2.* and your project is using JavaFX 1.3.*. As you can learn on official site, JavaFX is not backward compatible yet. Get newer library or rebuild sources with JavaFX 1.3.*

Comment: Thanks! Pretty sure that is the problem. I'm going to give the new JFXtras library a shot.